# Restore tensorflow model and use it for single input

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

While trying to get the trained model from this repo [im2latex-tensorflow](https://github.com/ritheshkumar95/im2latex-tensorflow) to work I downloaded the checkpoint files from [ckpt files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwbIUfIM1M8sc0tEMGk1NGlKZTA) which was provided in the repo

Don't know much about machine learning..Just want to see the output. After a bit of googling i tried restoring the model and graph.

```
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
import os

img_input='60ee89c612.png'

new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('weights_best.ckpt.meta')

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=8))

new_saver.restore(sess, "./weights_best.ckpt")

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Don't know how to proceed after this. How do i give `img_input`
as input to the program and get corresponding latex code for it.
To use the restored model i understand there needs to be 
an input node and and an output node to predict the output.
Help is highly appreciated

Comment: the repository mentioned that you can try using predict() in attention.py or Predict.ipynb. Have you tried those yet? Or do you want to do it using the import_meta_graph method?

Comment: predict() in Predict.ipynb uses np.load('pred_latex.npy') which is not available in the repo.I can't generate it without training. Since I want to simply use it and not train, the latter method is preferred.

Comment: I have doubts if the model given in the repo has weights stored in them though